# Azure Point to Site VPN on Same Network that is having Policy based Site-to-Site connection

Tags: azure, networking, vpn, azure-vpn

I am trying to create Point to Site connection on a Virtual Network that is having Policy-based Site to Site configured, so I am not getting any option to configure P2S. 
Any Recommendation How should I proceed with that.

I have already tried to make another Gateway in a separate VNet and peering it with the older one but not being able to connect to other VNet as Gateway transit is not enabled.

Comment: Any update on your side?

Comment: Hey Nancy! It seems this is impossible I tried multiple methods even I tried to connect with 2 Vnets with site to site and point to site on other  VNet but still no luck so I am working on recreation of route based gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure point to site VPN only supports to use **RouteBased** (dynamic), refer to this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways#models

So you need to use a **route based** VPN gateway to deploy P2S and S2S connection coexistence. If so, you need to create a new VPN gateway and remove the old one since an Azure Vnet gateway type cannot be changed from policy-based to route-based or the other way.

Additionally, if you have the Basic SKU VPN, the Basic SKU is considered a legacy SKU. The Basic SKU has certain feature limitations refer to [Gateway SKUs by feature set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-gateway-settings#feature). Also, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-multiple-policybased-rm-ps#azure-support-for-policy-based-vpn):

> The on-premises networks connecting through policy-based VPN devices
>   with this mechanism can only connect to the Azure virtual network;
>   they cannot transit to other on-premises networks or virtual networks
>   via the same Azure VPN gateway.

So, you may use a higher [gateway SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways#gwsku) for your deployment.